# r knitr Pandoc latex

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using the knitr package to make a table in PDF that I want to refer to within the document e.g.

```
\ref{table:name} on page \pageref{table:name}
```

Below is a sample of the function but I have trouble inserting a table's label

```
knitr::kable(head(iris), format = "latex")
```

In a latex document the command is like the one below

```
\label{table:name}
```

Is there a way to insert a label into a kable?

Comment: If you use table captions, you could simply add `\\label{myLab}` to the caption argument of kable.

Comment: this works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(captioner)
library(stringr)
table_nums <- captioner(prefix = "Table")
f.ref <- function(x){stringr::str_extract(table_nums(x), "[^:]*")}
```

```{r table1}
tab.1_cap <- table_nums(name = "tab_1")
knitr::kable(head(iris), caption = "Header data iris.")
```
````

Ahora podemos observar los datos de la base iris en la. Use `` inside this code `r f.ref("tab_1")` to run r codes within text in rmarkdown.